# Visual Studio stops debugging unity project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

Setup: `Unity 2017.4.16f1` / `2018.2.18f1`

I've got an own written `C#` library, using `.Net`. The library works fine in a `Winforms` application. In general it contacts a server application and fetches some data.

Now we want to visualize the data within Unity. For that I followed this guide: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html. In short: Drag and drop the library in the asset folder, add a new script and access the library. My first problem was the compatibility. Because, I used Unity `2017.4.16f1` first, I needed to downgrade the library from `.Net 4.7.2` to `.Net 4.6` and change the project settings to the same `.Net` framework. After getting rid of all the compiler errors, I ran into my current Problem.

I attached `Visual Studio 2017`to unity set up my breakpoint and started the app within `Unity`. The breakpoint is on the first call of a function from my custom library. The breakpoint is reached. But if i say 'Step over' (either via click or F10) the active line doesn't switch and I get back to `Unity`. It's like i never started debugging. `Unity` goes on like nothing happened.

After that i tried it with Unity `2018.2.18f1`. However, there is the same problem. The library isn't called.

Regarding some compatibility issues, I built the `Unity` project. No error occurs. Finally I stripped down the external library to a basic level. But again I got this strange behavior. Below is the script for unity and an example class from the custom library. Thank you for every advice.

`C#`:

```
[Serializable]
public class PostgreSQLParameters

[XmlElement(ElementName = "PostgreSQL_User", IsNullable = false)]
public string UserName
{
    get
    {
        return this.userName;
    }

    set
    {
        if (this.userName == value)
            return;
        this.userName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public PostgreSQLParameters()
{ }
```

`Unity`:

```
void Start () {

    string cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string pathVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");

    try
    {
        //this line has the break point, untill here all is ok
        //after the Debug steps in, I hit F10 here to get to the next line,
        //which should be the bracket befor the catch

        PostgreSQLParameters parameter = new PostgreSQLParameters();
    }  // The cursor should be here after hitting F10, but disappears only
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: is the dll compiled up for debug and copied with all the debug files?

Comment: Otherwise, it's not visible when attached to a different program. When you're debugging your library in its own project, you have those files generated for you. You'll need to move over those debug definitions to the Unity project to reference.

Comment: I don't want to debug the external library, I only want to debug the C# script from `Unity`. Hence, it should work with the release, too. However, I'll try it. Btw.: I updated the question.

Comment: Finally, I got it working (see below). A strange behavior lasts: if I set a breakpoint onto the line with the foreign code and "step over" (F10) i don't get to the next line of code. Instead, it behaves like hitting "continue". If I set a breakpoint on the line behind the call of the foreign library, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem are the dependencies. I compared the dependencies in my library, with them from the unity project within Visual Studio. It turns out on library wasn't linked in Unity: `System.Data.DataSetExtension`. There are two solutions:

A) If you don't need them, omit them in your library. Delete the reference in the library and compile again

B) Or if you need them and it's part of '.Net' do the following (not tested):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2017#adding-assembly-references-when-using-the-net-4x-api-compatibility-level

1. add a file, called mcs.rsp, in the asset root
2. Insert the line -r:System.Data.DataSetExtension (take the name of the reference you need)
3. Restart Unity